# GrapesJS How to implment Global Blocks

Tags: html, templates, content-management-system, grapesjs

I'm using Grapes JS for a CSM component on my website and I want to have global blocks such as headers and footers that can be added to a new page. The problem is when I change the global block I need it to change on all the pages they're used in. Is there a way to pull content from another page as blocks and have them render in the editor and not be editable?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting some kind of versioning on your blocks content (one or multiple) an attribute would be enough. Then you can check on `load` event for the version to be the latest and if not replace the component.